# JSON to insert in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails.

I need to insert the JSON response into my database.

The response received is:

```
{
"entity_name":"Test company",
"entity_relation":"2",
"address1":
{
"street_address":"street address for test company",
"city":"Test city",
"province":"Test province",
"postal_code":"411015"
},
"address2":
{
"street_address":"",
"city":"",
"province":"",
"postal_code":""
},
"phone_number":["1231231230"],
"entity_website":"www.testsite.com",
"entity_email":"a1@b1.com",
"entity_description":"This is the test description",
"controller":"frontend",
"action":"createorganization"
}
```

address is a separate table. How can I get:

```
address1[street_address]
address1[city]
address1[province]
address1[postal_code]
```

so I can insert in the database?

I did:

```
data = JSON.parse data
render json: data["address1"]
```

It outputs:

```
{
"street_address":"street address for test company",
"city":"Test city",
"province":"Test province",
"postal_code":"411015"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use data["address1"]["street_address"] to get the street address field.

Answer (score 0):

Its already working Make sure you are properly parsing it

```
data = JSON.parse('{
"entity_name":"Test company",
"entity_relation":"2",
"address1":
{
"street_address":"street address for test company",
"city":"Test city",
"province":"Test province",
"postal_code":"411015"
},
"address2":
{
"street_address":"",
"city":"",
"province":"",
"postal_code":""
},
"phone_number":["1231231230"],
"entity_website":"www.testsite.com",
"entity_email":"a1@b1.com",
"entity_description":"This is the test description",
"controller":"frontend",
"action":"createorganization"
}')
```

Returns the result

```
{
           "entity_name" => "Test company",
       "entity_relation" => "2",
              "address1" => {
        "street_address" => "street address for test company",
                  "city" => "Test city",
              "province" => "Test province",
           "postal_code" => "411015"
    },
              "address2" => {
        "street_address" => "",
                  "city" => "",
              "province" => "",
           "postal_code" => ""
    },
          "phone_number" => [
        [0] "1231231230"
    ],
        "entity_website" => "www.testsite.com",
          "entity_email" => "a1@b1.com",
    "entity_description" => "This is the test description",
            "controller" => "frontend",
                "action" => "createorganization"
}
```

Now you can directly access `data["address1"]`

```
$ data["address1"]

{
    "street_address" => "street address for test company",
              "city" => "Test city",
          "province" => "Test province",
       "postal_code" => "411015"
}
```